# "User-defined type not defined" for simple custom type

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-types

In Excel 2007 I have the following very simple code in VBA:

```
Public Type specType
    sb As Long
End Type


Private Sub MyButton_Click()
    Dim spec As specType

    '...
End Sub
```

When the button is clicked, i get a "User-defined type not defined" Error on the "Dim spec As specType" line... why? Do I have to move my user defined types to a special location?

Comment: You have to declare user-defined types in a module. Is all of the code that you've shown placed in one module?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out Types have to be defined *before* any functions in the module, otherwise they simply won't be recognized (without giving you an error).

Comment: Before any functions *or subroutines*.