# Why does VBA in Excel give a compiler error when using the type statement? Is there a way to activate the type statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble using the type statement in Excel VBA. When I try running some simple VBA code like below, I receive an error message highlighted over `Dim currentClient As ClientData` stating

Compile error:

User-defined type not defined

I even tried declaring values in the `currentClient` variable, but it was still generating an error.

```
Public Type ClientData
      EmployerName As String
      Wages as Double
   End Type

Sub TestProc()
     Dim currentClient As ClientData

End Sub
```

How can I use the Type statement in VBA?

Comment: That code runs fine for me.  Is all that code in the same module, and what type of module is it?

Comment: Yes. All that code is in the same module and it's a module that's part of the workbook it's in. The module doesn't have any special features. 


Do I need to check off something in references?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Is the `Public Type` at the *top* of the module, as shown in your post, or below `TestProc` ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679822/user-defined-type-not-defined-for-simple-custom-type

Comment: It's at the top of the module. I'm using the windows OS and it's declared before the Procedure.

Comment: Is the code in a standard module or an object module e.g. Sheet1, ThisWorkbook?

Comment: Is the code you posted the whole module content (plus, hopefully `Option Explicit`) ?

Comment: Apologies for the earlier comment. I had said that it was at the top of the module, but it actually wasn't. I had only placed the Type statement before the procedure that was going to use the Type variable

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved. I had to place the Type statement before ALL Procedures. I thought initially that the statement only needed to be placed right before the Procedure that was using the Type variable. But they need to be the first thing declared before all procedures and subroutines.